# Laravel create an array in postman and save in database

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am having troubles at this situation.
This is what I show in Postman
[image]

Controller

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
     $user =  Auth::guard('api');


        if ($user)
        {
            $parameters=new UserParameters();
            $parameters->id_user=Auth::guard('api')->id();
            $parameters->day=$request->day;

            if($parameters->save())
            {
                $times=$request->time;

                foreach ( $times as $time)
                {
                    $new_time = new TimeParameter();
                    $new_time->id_parameter = $parameters->id;
                    $new_time->time = $time[0];
                    $new_time->hour = $time[1];
                    $new_time->save();
                }

                return response()->json(['true' => false, 'message' => 'Saved!']);

            }


        }

        else
        {

            return response()->json(['error' => false, 'message' => 'User not found!']);

        }

    }
```

> I stuck at for loop.  How can I handle this situation ?

This is what i get in database 
[image]

Comment: What is the data type of your $times variable? could you add an image of the dd($times);

Comment: Could you try changing your data on the post man to time[0]['time'] = morning and time[0]['hour'] = 10:00 and so on. then send me the var_dump of the times again

Comment: array:2 [
  "day" => "everyday"
  "time" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "time" => "morning"
      "hour" => "10:00"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "time" => "evening"
      "hour" => "16:00"
    ]
  ]
]    

But when I execute it without dd it shows Trying to get property 'time' of non-object

Comment: well that data looks better, now on what line is the error?

Comment: it doesn't show the line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how your key's are named. time[0].time is not valid and maybe it is reading it to time[0] only. Which is why you are only getting the hours. 
time[0].time = 'morning';
time[0].hour = '10:00';
- then it will not count the .time or the .hour because that is not valid. then it would only make it time[0] which then explains why you are only getting the hours.

---

With the changes on the postman data that I asked you to do. You can try this solution.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
 $user =  Auth::guard('api');


    if ($user)
    {
        $parameters=new UserParameters();
        $parameters->id_user=Auth::guard('api')->id();
        $parameters->day=$request->day;

        if($parameters->save())
        {
            $data= $request->all();

            foreach ( $data['times'] as $time)
            {
                $new_time = new TimeParameter();
                $new_time->id_parameter = $parameters->id;
                $new_time->time = $time[0];
                $new_time->hour = $time[1];
                $new_time->save();
            }

            return response()->json(['true' => false, 'message' => 'Saved!']);

        }


    }

    else
    {

        return response()->json(['error' => false, 'message' => 'User not found!']);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

I don't know how your code works, because this `for ( $times as $time)` is not how `for` works.

Here is a explanation on `for`
https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php

**Solution**

The `as` on the `for` make me think your trying to use the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).
And here is how it works:

`foreach( $times as $time)` the `$time` is already a single record from the `array`

So when you do a `foreach` this is how it should look:

```
foreach ( $times as $time){
    $new_time = new TimeParameter();
    $new_time->id_parameter = $parameters->id;
    $new_time->time = $time->time;
    $new_time->hour = $time->hour;
    $new_time->save();
}
```

Comment: This is what I get   Illegal string offset &#039;time&#039;

Comment: varchar both of them

Comment: @alphal - I made a change in the code, could you try it?

Comment: it shows the same error Trying to get property &#039;time&#039; of non-object in file

Comment: Could you post the var_dump that @franzjoseph asked?

Comment: array:2 [
  0 => "10:00"
  1 => "16:00"
]

Comment: Is there any other way where I can show an array in postman and get the value in controller ?

Comment: You can do this `$data = $request->all();` and then make a `var_dump` in the `$data`

Comment: array:2 [
  "day" => "everyday"
  "time" => array:2 [
    0 => "10:00"
    1 => "16:00"
  ]
]